# Dúvida sobre o Searchview

Tags: android

Eu sou iniciante em programação e Android e tenho pesquisado muito e assistido muitas vídeo aulas e estou com um problemão com relação à busca com o searchview. Eu, apesar de pesquisar, testar e testar não estou conseguindo entender como fazer um motor de busca no meu app.

O meu aplicativo é um aplicativo de alimentação da minha dieta que tem uma activity com as categorias de alimentos(frutas, verduras, legumes, cereais, etc) e dentro dessas categorias tem os alimentos, por exemplo em frutas tem maçã, banana, mamão, em verduras rúcula, agrião, alface e assim por diante. Eu quero que quando eu clique nos alimentos abra uma activity com uma imagem do alimento, um audio falando sobre o alimento e textos sobre o alimento.

O que ocorre é que eu quero fazer um searchview que busque os alimentos das categorias e dê sugestões conforme eu for digitando as letras e quando eu clicar na opção de sugestão da busca ou quando eu digitar o nome do alimento por completo abra a activity do alimento. Só que eu já li muito, pesquisei e assisti vídeos e não estou conseguindo fazer esse searchview. Muitos vídeos explicam com exemplos, mas nesses exemplos tem muita coisa que eu não vou usar e como sou iniciante não sei quais as alterações que eu tenho que fazer do exemplo dos vídeos para a minha aplicação, tentei copiar e colar alguns códigos de sites e fazer asa mudanças necessárias que eu achei que deveriam ser feitas, mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

Eu gostaria de pedir, por favor, se algum colega pode me ensinar a fazer esse motor de busca voltado para a minha aplicação. Peço desculpas por eu ser tão iniciante assim, mas estou aprendendo e estou precisando tanto de ajuda com isso.

Eu cheguei até em pensar em pagar para alguém fazer essa parte da aplicação para mim de tão díficil que está para eu fazê-la.

Se alguem preferir me ensinar por skype pode ser, senão pode ser aqui pelo forum mesmo eu agradeço muito.

Atenciosamente,

Phil

Comment: Olá Phil, seja bem vindo ao SOpt. Sua pergunta me pareceu muito ampla para o modelo deste site. Aqui não é exatamente um fórum, mas com certeza você pode conseguir muitas respostas aqui, desde que elas se adequem ao site. Apesar de ela ser bem clara, e potencialmente interessante para outros usuários, é ampla demais, e seria necessário escrever um tutorial, não uma reposta objetiva. Aconselho que leia alguns tutoriais, vá tentando implementar o motor de busca, e conforme for recebendo erros, poste-os aqui, junto com o código.

Comment: Pra entender melhor como o SOpt funciona, dê uma olhada no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), e, na Central de Ajuda, especialmente [neste tópico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).